# Google Tink Crypto library - KeyGenerator AES implementation not found

Tags: android, tink

I'm running into this issue on a tablet device running Android KitKat as well as on a Samsung Tab-A on Lollipop. It has worked fine on an Acer tablet running Android M.

Here's the failure point:

```
private KeysetHandle getOrGenerateNewKeysetHandle() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        return new AndroidKeysetManager.Builder()
                .withSharedPref(getApplicationContext(), TINK_KEYSET_NAME, TINK_PREF_FILE_NAME)
                .withKeyTemplate(AeadKeyTemplates.AES256_GCM) // Failure point
                .withMasterKeyUri(ANDROID_KEYSTORE_TINK_MASTER_KEY_URI)
                .build()
                .getKeysetHandle();
    }
```

And then I initialize my AEAD when initializing Tink:

```
// google\Tink crypto
try {
    TinkConfig.register();
    aead = AeadFactory.getPrimitive(getOrGenerateNewKeysetHandle());
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Tink registered.");
} catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Tink failed to register or could not generate a keyset handle.");
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Tink failed to register: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Either way, Tink fails to initialize with the below caught message:

```
10-03 16:10:58.319 com.mycompany.myapp.debug E/MainActivity: Tink failed to register: KeyGenerator AES implementation not found
```

Is there a specific KeyTemplate I can replace the below with?

```
AeadKeyTemplates.AES256_GCM
```

Full Stacktrace:

```
10-03 17:25:45.235 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyGenerator AES implementation not found
10-03 17:25:45.245 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
10-03 17:25:45.255 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:170)
10-03 17:25:45.255 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:163)
10-03 17:25:45.255 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:135)
10-03 17:25:45.255 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.generateNewAeadKey(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:141)
10-03 17:25:45.265 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.getOrGenerateNewAeadKey(AndroidKeystoreKmsClient.java:128)
10-03 17:25:45.265 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.google.crypto.tink.integration.android.AndroidKeysetManager$Builder.withMasterKeyUri(AndroidKeysetManager.java:157)
10-03 17:25:45.265 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.getOrGenerateNewKeysetHandle(MainActivity.java:2520)
10-03 17:25:45.265 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.initializeRequiredAppComponents(MainActivity.java:2554)
10-03 17:25:45.265 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:230)
10-03 17:25:45.275 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-03 17:25:45.275 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-03 17:25:45.275 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-03 17:25:45.275 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-03 17:25:45.275 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-03 17:25:45.285 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-03 17:25:45.285 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-03 17:25:45.285 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-03 17:25:45.285 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-03 17:25:45.285 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 17:25:45.295 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-03 17:25:45.295 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-03 17:25:45.295 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-03 17:25:45.295 com.mycompany.myapp.debug W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 17:25:45.295 com.mycompany.myapp.debug E/MainActivity: GeneralSecurityException - Tink failed to register or could not generate a keyset handle: KeyGenerator AES implementation not found
10-03 17:25:45.295 com.mycompany.myapp.debug E/MainActivity: isMDMAPISupported: Exception ignored
```

Comment: Can you show me a full stack trace?

Comment: @ThaiDuong Hi Thai, I added it as an edit.

Comment: Thanks. I found a bug in AndroidKeysetManager. Please track the status of the fix in https://github.com/google/tink/issues/142.

Comment: Thanks @ThaiDuong. Any temporary workaround for my issue?

Comment: Mike, the issue is fixed and pushed to GitHub. We're working a bug fix release 1.2.1. In the meantime, you can also use the HEAD-SNAPSHOT version, https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/JAVA-HOWTO.md#snapshots, which would be updated in 1-2 hours.

Comment: The snapshot version was updated. Could you please try to see if it works for you?

Comment: @ThaiDuong thanks for getting to this so quickly, the issue is fixed and I'm no longer getting crashes on Lollipop or Kitkat devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **below worked as a temporary workaround when running into the issue on Tink v1.2.0**. For Android SDK below 23, we skip using the Keystore when building the keysetManager.

However, **this should no longer be an issue on Tink v1.2.1 (when it is released)** as I've tested the latest HEAD-SNAPSHOT and did not experience a crash.

```
    private KeysetHandle getOrGenerateNewKeysetHandle() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        AndroidKeysetManager.Builder keysetManagerBuilder = new AndroidKeysetManager.Builder()
                .withSharedPref(getApplicationContext(), TINK_KEYSET_NAME, TINK_PREF_FILE_NAME)
                .withKeyTemplate(AeadKeyTemplates.AES256_GCM);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            keysetManagerBuilder.withMasterKeyUri(ANDROID_KEYSTORE_TINK_MASTER_KEY_URI);
        } else {
            keysetManagerBuilder.doNotUseKeystore();
        }

        return keysetManagerBuilder.build().getKeysetHandle();
    }
```